# Typeahead - Bloodhound initialize() failed

Tags: typeahead.js, bloodhound

After HTML5 migration of a legacy JSP page, Bloodhound.initialize() method does not get triggered when the page load. This was working before the html5 migration. I am new to typeahead.js and any help would be really appreciated.

typeahead.js version - 0.10.1

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this issue. It is because a HTML comment tag place in the JSP which call from the prefetch url in Bloodhound. Once I removed the comment tag it works fine.